# Unable to interpret crash dump in Windbg

Tags: powershell, windbg, crash-dumps

I am working on the high CPU issue and captured task manager dump. We manage to identify the application (powershell.exe) that is causing the high CPU utilization but I am still new to windbg and trying to analyze the dump file. I noticed that the stack trace is showing binary, I thought the issue was related to Symbol Path but it is not showing any issue or error with arguments. Running !analyze -v on one of the dumps gives me the following:

```
PROCESS_BAM_CURRENT_THROTTLED: 0

PROCESS_BAM_PREVIOUS_THROTTLED: 0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 0000000000000000
   ExceptionCode: 80000003 (Break instruction exception)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 0

FAULTING_THREAD:  00002de4

PROCESS_NAME:  powershell.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x80000003 - {EXCEPTION}  Breakpoint  A breakpoint has been reached.

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  80000003

STACK_TEXT: 
000000ad`43cfce48 00007ffc`acf08c1f     : 00007ffc`00000007 00000000`00000000 00007ffc`981009d0 00007ffc`b04c9ed0 : ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0x14
000000ad`43cfce50 00007ffc`993c36ee     : ffffffff`fffffffe 000002a1`00491c00 000000ad`43cfd438 00000000`00000001 : KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0xef
000000ad`43cfd150 00007ffc`993c354c     : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000001 000002a1`7381bc80 00000000`ffffffff : clr!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx_SO_TOLERANT+0x62
000000ad`43cfd1b0 00007ffc`993c3345     : 000002a1`7381bc80 00000000`00000001 000000ad`43cfd1a8 000000ad`00000001 : clr!Thread::DoAppropriateWaitWorker+0x1e4
000000ad`43cfd2b0 00007ffc`993c3925     : 00007ffc`983db258 00007ffc`00000001 00007ffc`39b73020 000002a1`004914d0 : clr!Thread::DoAppropriateWait+0x7d
000000ad`43cfd330 00007ffc`9818107b     : 000000ad`43cfd580 00007ffc`ffffffff 000000ad`43cfd500 00007ffc`94d38b00 : clr!WaitHandleNative::CorWaitOneNative+0x165
000000ad`43cfd560 00007ffc`9818104e     : 000000ad`43cfd570 000002a1`004c8760 000000ad`43cfd580 000002a1`004c8760 : mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle, Int64, Boolean, Boolean)$##6003D51+0x1b
000000ad`43cfd590 00007ffc`965d92a9     : 000002a1`004c86e8 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(Int32, Boolean)$##6003D4B+0x2e
000000ad`43cfd5d0 00007ffc`965d652f     : 000002a1`001bcf58 000002a1`001c0260 000000ad`43cfd6c8 00000000`00000001 : Microsoft_PowerShell_ConsoleHost_ni!Microsoft.PowerShell.Executor.ExecuteCommandAsyncHelper(System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Pipeline, System.Exception ByRef, ExecutionOptions)$##6000115+0x2f9
000000ad`43cfd650 00007ffc`965d5a1c     : 000002a1`0003aaa0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 000002a1`000991f8 : Microsoft_PowerShell_ConsoleHost_ni!Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.DoRunspaceInitialization(Boolean, Boolean, System.String, System.String, System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1<System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.CommandParameter>)$##6000161+0x91f
000000ad`43cfd730 00007ffc`965926cb     : 000002a1`000843b0 000002a1`000991f8 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000001 : Microsoft_PowerShell_ConsoleHost_ni!Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.DoCreateRunspace(System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, System.String, System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1<System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.CommandParameter>)$##600015F+0x2dc
000000ad`43cfd7e0 00007ffc`965d5492     : 000002a1`0003aaa0 000002a1`00099fa8 00000000`00000000 00000000`ffffffff : Microsoft_PowerShell_ConsoleHost_ni!Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.CreateRunspace(System.Object)$##600015C+0x5b
000000ad`43cfd840 00007ffc`9659265a     : 000002a1`000843b0 000002a1`000991f8 00000000`00000001 000002a1`000852c8 : Microsoft_PowerShell_ConsoleHost_ni!Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.DoRunspaceLoop(System.String, Boolean, System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1<System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.CommandParameter>, Boolean, Boolean, System.String)$##600015A+0xa2
000000ad`43cfd8c0 00007ffc`965902ee     : 000002a1`000843b0 000002a1`00085240 00000000`00000000 00000000`8007000b : Microsoft_PowerShell_ConsoleHost_ni!Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.Run(Microsoft.PowerShell.CommandLineParameterParser, Boolean)$##6000158+0x1ba
000000ad`43cfd930 00007ffc`9658f9cb     : 00000000`00000000 000002a1`0007da50 000002a1`00080a48 00000000`00000000 : Microsoft_PowerShell_ConsoleHost_ni!Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.Start(System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceConfiguration, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String[])$##6000128+0x36e
000000ad`43cfd9c0 00007ffc`99266813     : 000002a1`000042b8 00000000`00000000 000002a1`000057d0 000002a1`737fce48 : Microsoft_PowerShell_ConsoleHost_ni!Microsoft.PowerShell.UnmanagedPSEntry.Start(System.String, System.String[])$##6000237+0x24b
000000ad`43cfdaa0 00007ffc`992666c8     : 00000000`00000004 00007ffc`993f00d3 00007ffc`980fdd98 00007ffc`993fd26c : clr!CallDescrWorkerInternal+0x83
000000ad`43cfdae0 00007ffc`993f05c6     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 000000ad`43cfdcc8 00007ffc`97cc6e12 : clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0x4e
000000ad`43cfdb20 00007ffc`993f0a7f     : 00007ffc`97cc6e12 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 000000ad`43cfdd50 : clr!CallDescrWorkerReflectionWrapper+0x1a
000000ad`43cfdb70 00007ffc`981d6560     : 000002a1`000042b8 000002a1`00005c18 000002a1`00004d48 00000000`00000000 : clr!RuntimeMethodHandle::InvokeMethod+0x45f
000000ad`43cfe180 00007ffc`981c155e     : 000002a1`00005790 00000000`00000006 00000014`43cfe200 00007ffc`39b64958 : mscorlib_ni!System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Object[])$##6004638+0x80
000000ad`43cfe1f0 00007ffc`99266813     : 000002a1`000046b0 000002a1`000042b8 00007ffc`00040100 000002a1`00005790 : mscorlib_ni!System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(System.Object, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo)$##6004636+0x8e
000000ad`43cfe270 00007ffc`992666c8     : 000000ad`43cfea88 00007ffc`993f8fb2 000000ad`43cfea88 00000000`00000000 : clr!CallDescrWorkerInternal+0x83
000000ad`43cfe2c0 00007ffc`99266d9d     : 00000000`00000006 000000ad`43cfedf0 000000ad`43cff2e0 000000ad`43cfea88 : clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0x4e
000000ad`43cfe300 00007ffc`9935539a     : 000000ad`43cff300 00000000`00040100 000000ad`43cff300 00000000`00040100 : clr!MethodDescCallSite::CallTargetWorker+0xf8
000000ad`43cfe410 00007ffc`99354ef6     : 000000ad`43cff298 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00007ffc`99449a11 : clr!DispatchInfo::InvokeMemberWorker+0xade
000000ad`43cfefc0 00007ffc`99354c8c     : 00000000`00000000 000000ad`43cff6f8 00000000`00000000 000000ad`43cff1e0 : clr!DispatchInfo::InvokeMemberDebuggerWrapper+0x1c6
000000ad`43cff120 00007ffc`99355782     : 000002a1`73859240 00000000`00000000 000002a1`73a8ff18 000002a1`73887cd0 : clr!DispatchInfo::InvokeMember+0x478
000000ad`43cff410 00007ffc`993555dd     : 000002a1`73a8ff00 00007ff7`0897d3d0 000000ad`43cff5c0 00000000`60020004 : clr!InternalDispatchImpl_Invoke+0x1ed
000000ad`43cff530 00007ffc`9935551e     : 000002a1`7381bc80 000000ad`00000001 00000000`00000000 00007ffc`9974a174 : clr!InternalDispatchImpl_Invoke_CallBack+0xb2
000000ad`43cff590 00007ff7`089714e6     : 000002a1`73ad1880 00000000`00000000 000002a1`73ad1ab0 00000000`00000000 : clr!InternalDispatchImpl_Invoke_Wrapper+0xf8
000000ad`43cff630 00007ff7`08971a84     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000007 000002a1`73ad1a90 00000000`00000000 : powershell!LaunchManagedMonad+0x456
000000ad`43cff860 00007ff7`08972f6d     : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : powershell!wmain+0x454
000000ad`43cffa00 00007ffc`b02a84d4     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : powershell!operator delete+0x291
000000ad`43cffa40 00007ffc`b04c1791     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
000000ad`43cffa70 00000000`00000000     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21


STACK_COMMAND:  ~0s; .ecxr ; kb

SYMBOL_NAME:  clr!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx_SO_TOLERANT+62

MODULE_NAME: clr

IMAGE_NAME:  clr.dll

BUCKET_ID_MODPRIVATE: 1

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  BREAKPOINT_80000003_clr.dll!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx_SO_TOLERANT

OS_VERSION:  10.0.14393.4886

BUILDLAB_STR:  rs1_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

IMAGE_VERSION:  4.7.3890.0

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {db6c2e2e-ad6b-5c1a-411e-e86562abef3e}

Followup:     MachineOwner
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction, in terms of making sense of this entry, and what I can do about it?

Comment: The stack trace shows nothing of interest. You might be on the wrong thread (check all the threads in the process & use [!runaway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-runaway)). High CPU usage should be diagnosed with [WPR or WPA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/). High CPU with `WaitForMultipleObjectsEx` is either a tight loop without a proper wait time or the function failing since the function, by definition, will relinquish CPU time and resume when an object is alerted or the timeout has elapsed.

Comment: As Neitsa commented the thread with stack that is waiting for objects is not the the thread that turns out to be culprit  those Waiting functions normally relinquish cpu  until the object they are waiting is alerted   you can also try using procdump from sysinternals with -c argument to make dumps when cpu threshhold is crossed

Comment: A single crash dump is not a good basis for a high CPU analysis. You might be unlucky and have captured the dump at a point where it does nothing of interest. If yoiu insist on doing that analysis with crash dumps (and not with WPR/WPA), then take many of them and make a statistics of callstacks.